# Почему html-тег 'meta description' не переведен?

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

У меня есть этот код Python, который работает очень хорошо.

Я могу перевести все свои HTML-теги, кроме одного: `<meta name="description" content="...">`

может ли кто-нибудь помочь мне с решением? Я не знаю, почему не работает.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.formatter import HTMLFormatter
from googletrans import Translator
import requests

translator = Translator()

class UnsortedAttributes(HTMLFormatter):
    def attributes(self, tag):
        for k, v in tag.attrs.items():
            yield k, v

files_from_folder = r"c:\carte\1"

use_translate_folder = True

destination_language = 'fr'

extension_file = ".html"

import os

directory = os.fsencode(files_from_folder)

def recursively_translate(node):
    for x in range(len(node.contents)):
        if isinstance(node.contents[x], str):
            if node.contents[x].strip() != '':
                try:
                    node.contents[x].replaceWith(translator.translate(node.contents[x], dest=destination_language).text)
                except:
                    pass
        elif node.contents[x] != None:
            recursively_translate(node.contents[x])

amount = 1
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    print(filename)
    if filename == 'y_key_e479323ce281e459.html' or filename == 'directory.html':
        continue
    if filename.endswith(extension_file):
        with open(os.path.join(files_from_folder, filename), encoding='utf-8') as html:
            soup = BeautifulSoup('<pre>' + html.read() + '</pre>', 'html.parser')
            for title in soup.findAll('title'):
                recursively_translate(title)

            for meta in soup.findAll('meta', {'name':'description'}):
                try:
                    meta['content'] = recursively_translate(meta['content'])
                except:
                    pass


            for p in soup.findAll('p', class_='text_obisnuit2'):
                    recursively_translate(p)



        print(f'{filename} translated ({amount})')
        amount += 1
        soup = soup.encode(formatter=UnsortedAttributes()).decode('utf-8')
        new_filename = f'{filename.split(".")[0]}_{destination_language}.html'
        if use_translate_folder:
            try:
                with open(os.path.join(files_from_folder+r'\translated', new_filename), 'w', encoding='utf-8') as new_html:
                    new_html.write(soup[5:-6])
            except:
                os.mkdir(files_from_folder+r'\translated')
                with open(os.path.join(files_from_folder+r'\translated', new_filename), 'w', encoding='utf-8') as new_html:
                    new_html.write(soup[5:-6])
        else:
            with open(os.path.join(files_from_folder, new_filename), 'w', encoding='utf-8') as html:
                html.write(soup[5:-6])
```

**test.html**

```
<html>
<head>

    <title>It really helps me do great things for her</title>
    
    <meta name="description" content="What I LOVE to do and what I don't love">

    <p class="text_obisnuit2"><em>Buckingham has a new book called Love</em></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Я не знаю Питона. Но вы можете фиктивно создать новый тег в конце файла, например, `<p class="TEST">это тест</p>`, и вы можете выполнить синтаксический анализ с помощью регулярного выражения из тега `description` в этом новом теге. Снова переведите с помощью Python этот тег `<p class="TEST">`, затем проанализируйте содержимое обратно в тег `description`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**изменить с помощью этой строки вместо фактической строки:**

```
node.contents[x].replaceWith(translator.translate(node.contents[x], dest=destination_language).text)
```

**и эта часть:**

```
        for meta in soup.findAll('meta', {'name':'description'}):
            try:
                meta['content'] = translator.translate(meta['content'], dest=destination_language).text
            except:
                pass
```

**Таким образом, полный код должен выглядеть так. Обновляю и ставлю и другие теги, чтобы было намного лучше.**

```
# pip install googletrans==4.0.0rc1


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.formatter import HTMLFormatter
from googletrans import Translator
import requests

translator = Translator()

class UnsortedAttributes(HTMLFormatter):
    def attributes(self, tag):
        for k, v in tag.attrs.items():
            yield k, v

files_from_folder = r"c:\carte"

use_translate_folder = True

destination_language = 'fr'

extension_file = ".html"

import os

directory = os.fsencode(files_from_folder)

def recursively_translate(node):
    for x in range(len(node.contents)):
        if isinstance(node.contents[x], str):
            if node.contents[x].strip() != '':
                try:
                    node.contents[x].replaceWith(translator.translate(node.contents[x], dest=destination_language).text)
                except:
                    pass
        elif node.contents[x] != None:
            recursively_translate(node.contents[x])

amount = 1
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    print(filename)
    if filename == 'y_key_e479323ce281e459.html' or filename == 'directory.html':
        continue
    if filename.endswith(extension_file):
        with open(os.path.join(files_from_folder, filename), encoding='utf-8') as html:
            soup = BeautifulSoup('<pre>' + html.read() + '</pre>', 'html.parser')
            for title in soup.findAll('title'):
                recursively_translate(title)

            for meta in soup.findAll('meta', {'name':'description'}):
                try:
                    meta['content'] = translator.translate(meta['content'], dest=destination_language).text
                except:
                    pass

# translate the html tag <h1 class="den_articol" itemprop="name">Text Text</h1>

            for h1 in soup.findAll('h1', {'itemprop':'name'}, class_='den_articol'):
                    recursively_translate(h1)



# translate the html tag <p class="text_obisnuit">Text Text</p>

            for p in soup.findAll('p', class_='text_obisnuit'):

                    recursively_translate(p)

# translate the html tag <p class="DONO">Text Text</p>

            for p in soup.findAll('p', class_='DONO'):

                    recursively_translate(p)  


        print(f'{filename} translated ({amount})')
        amount += 1
        soup = soup.encode(formatter=UnsortedAttributes()).decode('utf-8')
        new_filename = f'{filename.split(".")[0]}_{destination_language}.html'
        if use_translate_folder:
            try:
                with open(os.path.join(files_from_folder+r'\translated', new_filename), 'w', encoding='utf-8') as new_html:
                    new_html.write(soup[5:-6])
            except:
                os.mkdir(files_from_folder+r'\translated')
                with open(os.path.join(files_from_folder+r'\translated', new_filename), 'w', encoding='utf-8') as new_html:
                    new_html.write(soup[5:-6])
        else:
            with open(os.path.join(files_from_folder, new_filename), 'w', encoding='utf-8') as html:
                html.write(soup[5:-6])
```